# inter- prefix means between but interact has a whole different meaning than -inter or act, why is that?

Tags: suffixes, prefixes

I just started to dig into suffixes and prefixes. But I couldn't understand how do they exactly change the meaning of the word that they are appended.

For example re- means again, retake means take again. Inter- means between, but interact means acting in a way that you have an effect on something. Interact has no connection with between. Why is that?

Comment: I think you mean `re-` not `-re`. Not all words starting with what appears to be a suffix _are_ suffixed.

Comment: @marcellothearcane edited. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Inter-** has the following definitions:

> 1. Between; among.
>      ‘inter-agency’, ‘interblend’
> 2. Mutually; reciprocally.
>      ‘interactive’

The **between** is the [fourth definition](https://lexico.com/en/definition/between):

> Indicating a connection or relationship involving two or more parties.

According to [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/interact#etymonline_v_34706), **interact** means:

> "act on each other, act reciprocally," 1805, from inter- + act (v.).

In addition, [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/interact) defines it thus:

> 1. Act in such a way as to have an effect on each other.

Comment: Seems like resources I looked from doesn't give the exact definition. Thank you. Are there a tool that finds base word of a given word? For example I want to learn base word of duplicate, how can I do that?

Comment: This question is general reference. The correct response is to direct the OP to the Help Center (which gives easily available resources) and close-vote. ELU is aimed at 'linguists ...'. It's the only website I know that is. Wouldn't it be good to maintain standards?

Comment: @J.Smith Etymonline is good for that.